# Collect data from table and pass it through link as query string

Tags: c#, sql-server, query-string

In "ads" table where those info into controllers below will be stored, the table has "AdsID" column which generate automatic  number of each row. So what i am looking for is after inserting the info form controllers inside table , get the AdsID number of row which just created when the button clicked and pass the row number "AdsID" and "AdsTit" through EditAds.aspx

```
protected void adNewQdadsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);

                if (RegInteFileUploadImg1.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg2.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg3.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg4.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg5.HasFile)
                {


                    var files = new[] { FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, FileExtentio3, FileExtentio4, FileExtentio5 };
                    files = files.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
                    var extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".png" };
                    if ((files.Except(extensions).Count()) <= 0)
                    {
                        if (RegDropDownList3.SelectedValue == "no")
                        {
                            AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                            adsstutslbel.Text = "- Please select ads status";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }


                        if (DropDownList11.SelectedValue == "no")
                        {
                            AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                            adscondlbel.Text = "- Please select ads condition";
                        }


                        string sqlstatment = @"INSERT INTO ads (Section, Category, AdsTit, AdsDesc, Country, State,AdsDate,City, AdsPrice, Img1, img2, img3, img4,img5, Wtags, QAdsTeleNum,Condition, Status,Maker,Year,Gear,RoomNo, Space,Shower,Garage,Currency,extlink,AdType,approvAds,QAdsEmail)
        VALUES (@Section, @Category, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Img1, @img2, @img3,
        @img4, @img5, @Wtags, @QAdsTeleNum,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage,@Currency, @extlink,@AdType,@approvAds,@QAdsEmail)";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstatment, cn);


                        String shw = "Y";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", RegSecdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maker", makervalue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Yearvalue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gear", Gearvalue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", RoomNum);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Space", areasize);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", RegCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", NyAdsDesc);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cookie.Value);


                        string imgnouser = "/images/general/nouser.jpg";

                        if (RegInteFileUploadImg1.HasFile)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", RegInteFileUploadImg1.FileName);
                            RegInteFileUploadImg1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + RegInteFileUploadImg1.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (RegInteFileUploadImg2.HasFile)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", RegInteFileUploadImg2.FileName);
                            RegInteFileUploadImg2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + RegInteFileUploadImg2.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", imgnouser);
                        }

                        cn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.Text = "Error: The file should have .png or .jpg format only";
                        AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                        return;
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    string sqlstatment2 = @"INSERT INTO ads (Section, Category, AdsTit, AdsDesc, Country, State,AdsDate,City, AdsPrice, Wtags, QAdsTeleNum,Condition, Status,Maker,Year,Gear,RoomNo, Space,Shower,Garage,extlink,AdType,approvAds,QAdsEmail) VALUES (@Section, @Category, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Wtags, @QAdsTeleNum,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage, @extlink,@AdType,@approvAds,@QAdsEmail)";


                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstatment2, cn);

                    String SHO = "Y";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", RegSecdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maker", makervalue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Yearvalue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gear", Gearvalue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", RoomNum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Space", areasize);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", RegCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", NyAdsDesc);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adsDate", DateTime.Now);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", AddAdsCurencyLBL.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extlink", extlinktxtbox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdType", QUAD);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@approvAds", AdsAprov);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsEmail", QuickAdsEmailTxtBox.Text);


                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

                string QAdsID = string.Empty;
                string QADSTit = string.Empty;


                using (SqlCommand SendMailcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT AdsID FROM ads WHERE QAdsEmail = @QAdsEmail AND AdsTit=@AdsTit OR QAdsTeleNum=@QAdsTeleNum"))
                {
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsEmail", QuickAdsEmailTxtBox.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsTeleNum", QuickAdsMobNumTxtBox.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Connection = cn;

                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = SendMailcmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            QAdsID = sdr["AdsID"].ToString();
                            QADSTit = sdr["AdsTit"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                }

                Response.Redirect("EditAds.aspx?Name=" + this.addadstittxtbx.Text );


    }
```

Comment: It will help Simon if the downvotes are accompanied with an explanation.  Simon I would assume this is because you question is hard to read/understand.  Can you simplify your question?  Can you reduce the posted code example to include just the relevant lines?

Comment: @destination-data thanks for your reply i have update the post hopeful that will explain more clearly

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand your question correctly you're trying to get the ID of the inserted row back to your application?

If so, consider the following. Since you seem to be inserting single rows, and assuming you're using SqlServer 2005 or later it's fairly simple.

You can use the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) with your insert statement and immediately return the ID for each row. If you construct your query like

```
INSERT INTO table (<column>)
    OUTPUT inserted.<column>
    VALUES (<@parameter>)
```

You can simply use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` or `cmd.ExecuteReader()` to get the newly inserted ID.

/edit: Trying to implement it in your code (ommitting the ParameterValues since that stays the same)

```
// initialization stuff left out because it stays the same [...]
string sqlstatment = @"INSERT INTO ads (Section, Category, AdsTit, AdsDesc, Country, State,AdsDate,City, AdsPrice, Img1, img2, img3, img4,img5, Wtags, QAdsTeleNum,Condition, Status,Maker,Year,Gear,RoomNo, Space,Shower,Garage,Currency,extlink,AdType,approvAds,QAdsEmail) 
    OUTPUT inserted.AdsID        
    VALUES (@Section, @Category, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Img1, @img2, @img3,
    @img4, @img5, @Wtags, @QAdsTeleNum,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage,@Currency, @extlink,@AdType,@approvAds,@QAdsEmail)";
// ommitting parameter stuff [...]

cn.Open();
string QAdsID = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string; // cast or convert the proper data type here...
```

You can of course output multiple inserted values but then you'd need a `DataReader` or a `DataAdapter` instead of `ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: thanks for your reply but could explain it by updating my code, then i can understand exactly how its work cause i am little confuse of how i can do as you mention into my code

Comment: thanks, but i tried as you mention and after the line of string QAdsID... I added " Response.Redirect("EditAds.aspx?AdTit=" + this.addadstittxtbx.Text + "&AdNum=" + QAdsID); " but it didnt get the AdsID Valueas the link it appear like that:  http://www.berava.com/EditAds.aspx?AdTit=test&AdNum=